# Genetic Algorithm doesn't improve

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm developing Tetris game using AI and Genetic Algorithm.

The AI has the objective to "try" each available moves with the current Tetraminos and board and choose the best one. To choose the best one i have a fitness function that return a score for a move inside that board.

For example, i count all the holes inside the board after the move and multiply that values with a variable.

```
def evaluate_move(self, board: Board, shape):
    score = 0
    board.check_rows(shape)

    score += self.aggregate_height * board.aggregate_height()
    score += self.bumpiness * board.bumpiness()
    score += self.holes * board.holes()
    score += self.columns_with_holes * board.columns_with_holes()
    score += self.number_of_pits * board.number_of_pits()
    score += self.cleared_rows * board.line_cleared
    return score
```

Each variable like `self.aggregate_height` etc are based on the genetic algorithm.

So, each chromosome inside the population generate at first random values that will be passed to the AI

```
self.aggregate_height = random.uniform(-3, 0)
self.bumpiness = random.uniform(-3, 0)
self.holes = random.uniform(-3, 0)
self.columns_with_holes = random.uniform(-3, 0)
self.number_of_pits = random.uniform(-3, 0)
self.cleared_rows = random.uniform(0, 3)
```

Each value is normalized in a `(-1,1)` range like this:

```
def normalize(value):
    return value / 3
```

Then, after each generation, applies crossover and mutate like this:

```
def crossover(self, other_parent):
    """Create a crossover of the best parents."""
    child = GeneticAgent()
    child.aggregate_height = self.aggregate_height if random.randint(0, 1) == 0 else other_parent.aggregate_height
    child.bumpiness = self.bumpiness if random.randint(0, 1) == 0 else other_parent.bumpiness
    child.holes = self.holes if random.randint(0, 1) == 0 else other_parent.holes
    child.columns_with_holes = self.columns_with_holes if random.randint(0,
                                                                         1) == 0 else other_parent.columns_with_holes
    child.number_of_pits = self.number_of_pits if random.randint(0, 1) == 0 else other_parent.number_of_pits
    child.cleared_rows = self.cleared_rows if random.randint(0, 1) == 0 else other_parent.cleared_rows

    return child

def mutation(self):
    """Mutating the offsprings generated from crossover to maintain variation in the population."""
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.aggregate_height += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.bumpiness += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.holes += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.columns_with_holes += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.number_of_pits += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    if numpy.random.random() < configuration.MUTATION_PERCENTAGE:
        self.cleared_rows += random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    self.normalize_values()
```

The parameters of the genetic algorithm are those:

```
# GENETIC ALGORITHM
NUMBER_OF_POPULATION = 200
NUMBER_OF_GENERATION = 200
NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER = 10
MUTATION_PERCENTAGE = 0.1
NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 5
```

The problem is that i don't see really improvement. After 7 generations the best one got a score of 70000+, after this all the others generation got worst results.
The score of the each chromosome is the score that the AI got in the game / `NUMBER_OF_GAMES`
So, each AI get the values from a chromosome, test all the possible moves, does the best one found and keep going on until the end of this game. If this AI already played `NUMBER_OF_GAMES` games, then return the average points for game. After all the AIs are done, applies crossover and then mutate, and repeat.

EDIT: Tournament Crossover

```
def select_crossover_parents(population, tetris_fitness):
    crossover_parents = []
    for i in range(configuration.NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER):
        best_index = None
        indexes = random.sample(range(0, configuration.NUMBER_OF_POPULATION - 1), 15)
        for index in indexes:
            if (best_index is None) or (tetris_fitness[index] > tetris_fitness[best_index]):
                best_index = index

        crossover_parents.append(population[best_index])
    return crossover_parents
```

Another file...

```
crossover_parents_total = algorithm_manager.select_crossover_parents(population, tetris_fitness)
while len(population) != (configuration.NUMBER_OF_POPULATION - len(parents)):
    crossover_parents = random.sample(crossover_parents_total, 2)                  
    population.append(crossover_parents[0].crossover(crossover_parents[1]))
```

Comment: Your mutation probability is higher than I would expect. Also, 10 parents for a crossover is pretty high. Also, I don't see where you use `NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER`

Comment: I can test with lower mutation probability and crossover parents. 
 `NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER` is used to "store" the best scorers and, from them, generate  `NUMBER_OF_POPULATION  - NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER` new chromosome and add again the crossover parents to the generation, so that i don't loose the best scorer parameters. I can post where i used it if that could be the error

Comment: You hold onto the top 10 individuals from each generation (this is 5% elitism, which isn't bad). However, if those same 10 individuals are the ones that participate in crossover operations, you are converging way too early and that's why you don't see any improvement. Use a roulette wheel or tournament selection scheme to select parents for crossover, to mitigate this problem

Comment: I tried to implement a tournament selection like this. I take all the population, i take 15 random index from the entire array, i see the best score of those 15 chromosome, i add the best as crossover_parents. Then a choose other 15 index at random and repeat the process for  `NUMBER_PARENTS_CROSSOVER` so that i get 10 crossover parents, then i choose 2 randomly from those and generate a new chromosome, and i repeat until the population is complete. Then i add back the 5% elitims. Sound correct? PS: Added the code to the main question

Comment: 15:1 (15 enter, 1 wins) is way too much selection pressure. I'd recommend no more than 5:1 in a tournament. Typical choices are 2-3:1

Comment: Changed to 3 enter and 1 wins. Other suggestion? I will try leaving the training going tomorrow to see if there are any progress